# php curl post fails from within apache without proxy

Tags: php, apache, curl, proxy

I have a php script, called from a web page (server is Apache debian 6.03), which does a GET and a POST both using curl.  The GET is fine. The POST fails if php curl goes directly to the network but works fine if I use charles as a proxy.  (Haven't tried other proxies.)

In particular, if I add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "localhost:8888" );
```

to my script (with charles runningon 8888) it succeeds.  Otherwise I get:

```
"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request".
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oops.  My script used cookies in the post and there was white space at the beginning of the cookie string which I constructed.  Adding a 'trim' fixed the problem.

Sorry.